# Dictionary Value Not Decreasing

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tkinter

So I'm developing this GUI for a list program as a class project, everything works fine except for decreasing the dictionary value. The entire code block:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("ListGUI")
items = {}

def update_listbox():
    clear_listbox()
    for key in sorted(items):
        if items.get(key) > 1:
            lb_items.insert("end", '%s (%d)' % (key, items[key]))
        else:
            lb_items.insert("end", key)

def clear_listbox():
    lb_items.delete(0, "end")

def add_item():
    item = txt_input.get()
    if item != '':
        if item in items:
            items[item] = items.get(item) + 1
        else:
            items[item] = 1
    update_listbox()
    txt_input.delete(0, "end")

def del_item():
    item = lb_items.get("active")
    if item in items:
        if items.get(item) > 1:
            items[item] = items.get(item) - 1
        else:
            items.pop(item)
    update_listbox()

txt_input = Entry(window, width = 15)
txt_input.pack()

btn_add = Button(window, text = "Add item", command = add_item)
btn_add.pack()

lb_items = Listbox(window)
lb_items.pack()

btn_del = Button(window, text = "Delete item", command = del_item)
btn_del.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

The part that isn't working as it should is the embedded if statement in this block:

```
def del_item():
    item = lb_items.get("active")
    if item in items:
        if items.get(item) > 1:
            items[item] = items.get(item) - 1
        else:
            items.pop(item)
    update_listbox()
```

As I see it, it should decrease the value of the dictionary value given the key, however, it doesn't work. The pop works, but decreasing the value doesn't.

EDIT:

Code block fixed by splitting obtained string variable from the list box.

```
def del_item():
    item = lb_items.get("active")
    item = item.split(' ')
    item = item[0]
    if item in items:
        if items.get(item) > 1:
            items[item] = items.get(item) - 1
        else:
            items.pop(item)
    update_listbox()
```

Thank you to those who pointed out my string error.

Comment: If you add "abc" to the list twice and then try to delete it, `lb_items.get("active")` will return "abc (2)". "abc (2)" is not an element of your dictionary. "abc" is an element of your dictionary, but that's different from "abc (2)".

Comment: The value you get from the listbox will be a string. You're comparing it to an integer.

Comment: @Kevin that does seem to be my issue, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: A little debugging will show that `item` is probably not what you think it is inside of `del_item`. The first step in debugging should always be to validate your assumptions about what values the variables contain.

Comment: be aware that if the user types something with a space in it, your fix won't  work.